# How can I get specific values of my query? within mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

I have  a table of 5 x 5 frames, I need to show the name of the book , year and location on each frame,the question is if is posible  with just one query like

```
$res = SELECT * FROM books LIMIT 15
```

place each value in a random order within  the frame or necessarily I have to do many queries, one for name, other for autor, and other for location, finally the out put should be something like the following picture

[image]

I am trying to use while and for each but I can achieve the purpose

this is a test code

```
<?php
 include("conexion.php");  
$res = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM catalogos  ",$conexion);
$arreglo = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$arreglo[] = $row;
}
foreach ($arreglo as $rows){
$dato1= $rows[1];
$dato2=$rows[6];
$dato3=$rows[7];
}
```

and this is the test table

```
<table width="657" height="71" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><? echo"$data1";?></td>
    <td><? echo "$data2";?></td>
    <td><? echo "$data3";?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but in data 2 and 3 there is no values

Comment: Include your codes in your questions. and stop using `mysql_*` syntaxes, they are already depecrated

Comment: <?php
 include("conexion.php");  




$res = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM books",$conexion);

$arreglo = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

$array[] = $row;


}

foreach ($array as $rows){


$data1= $rows[1];

$data2=$rows[6];

$data3=$rows[7];
}

Comment: In your question please, not in the comment

Comment: That means one <td> will contain data & next <td> should be blank...right?

Comment: exactly,because in the blank space I will show the cover, but for now I am practicing in a table with three frames trying to place name1, name2 ,name 3 on each frame

Comment: I did what you told me but it still giving me only the first record and I have 6 records on my DB

Answer (score 0):

Use this before foreach...

```
shuffle($arreglo);
```

You will get different values every times.

Comment: yes it works, but only returns one row, how do I can get the book's name from the next 3 rows and place it on each frame. For example i have  $rows[1] it below to the name, and until the $rows[5] finish the first row, I thing that $row[6]; could be the name of the next book but it doesn't return  any value